# What is the difference between child orgUnits and descendants in Valence?

Tags: desire2learn

An unfiltered call to the /d2l/api/lp/1.2/orgstructure APIs seems to return the same set of all children/descendants, for either the children or descendant calls.

I'm really trying to get immediate children, of any orgUnitType.

/d2l/api/lp/(D2LVERSION: version)/orgstructure/(D2LID: orgUnitId)/children/
/d2l/api/lp/(D2LVERSION: version)/orgstructure/(D2LID: orgUnitId)/descendants/

Answer (score 0):

Child org units are immediate children while descendant org units encompass immediate children, children of children, and other org units in the org structure directed acyclic graph which have the specified org unit in their ancestry. It's also strongly recommended that you use the paged version of [that call](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-orgstructure-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-children-paged-) to avoid running into performance issues on a production instance.

You may be seeing identical responses if the specified org unit does not have any children which have children of their own.